# mina 2.0.13 + websocket + buffer.capacity

Tags: sockets, web, buffer, mina

Background:
I am sending data by mina web socket (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/DIRMINA-907) which is already patched the buf issue..

I used to send the json message through the web socket around 50 bytes.. sometimes, it will goes up to 70 bytes...

The problem is: 
at initial, the IOBuffer.capacity() is 2048 --> 2048 --> 1024 --> 1024 -> 512 -> 512 -> 256 -> 256 -> 128 -> 128 -> 64 -> 64 -> 64 -> 64

If the json message becomes 70 bytes. It will split into two message in messageReceived(IoSession session, Object message). Is there any way that i can solve this problem.

I can store the incomplete message, but it will raise another issue such as 2 json messages or 1 valid json message with 1 invalid json message.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are using TCP with MINA. When a big message is sent over TCP it gets split into smaller chunks to fit into smaller packets. TCP makes sure that the packet data arrives in the correct order when it arrives at it's destination.

What's happening is that your JSON message gets split while being sent over the network. Even though it arrives at the destination in order, you need to put together the two chunks.

The MINA user guide has a good example of how to accomplish this, it should help you out. You can find it [here](https://mina.apache.org/mina-project/userguide/ch9-codec-filter/ch9-codec-filter.html)

Answer (score 0):

Finally, i solve it by adding

acceptor.getSessionConfig().setMinReadBufferSize(2048);

into my code.

Set the minimum read buffer to prevent the message split into 2 pieces..
I know that it is not a prefect solution. but my message won't larger than 2K.

jython234 suggested solution is not fit for my need.